# Touchpad scroll not working in Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 15

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad, synaptics

I recently bought the **Lenovo ThinkPad Yoga 15** (2015 edition). I dual booted Ubuntu 14.04 LTS alongside pre-installed Windows 8.1. 
Everything works great **except the touch pad scroll**. **I want to make the vertical finger scroll work**. I have an **external** Logitech M510 (wireless) **mouse** connected and **works** smooth. Ever since I have been trying to make scroll work but no luck.

Here are the **configuration details** of the touch pad on my ThinkPad:

> I: Bus=0003 Vendor=06cb Product=75e9 Version=0111
>   N: Name="SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04"
>   P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-6/input0
>   S:Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-6/2-6:1.0/0003:06CB:75E9.0001/input/input9
>   U: Uniq=
>   H: Handlers=mouse0 event7
>   B: PROP=2
>   B: EV=b
>   B: KEY=400 0 0 0 0 0   B: ABS=260800000000003

**Here is the output of `xinput`:**

> ⎡ Virtual core pointer     id=2   [master pointer  (3)]
>   ⎜     ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                  id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
>   ⎜     ↳ SYNAPTICS Synaptics Touch Digitizer V04     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
>   ⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
>   ⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
>       ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 3D Camer           id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ Intel(R) RealSense(TM) 3D Camer           id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
>       ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]

I don't find any possible solution to this fix. I tried tor run few commands matching Synaptics configuration to install the drivers but it didn't work out for me.

Is there any possible fix to this problem?
Any sort of help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to gez "edge scroll" to work or are you talking about -finger scroll?

Comment: @Mr. Gosh : Sorry for not specifying in question. I am trying to make the finger scroll work(vertical scroll).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.