# Several input devices (incl. Trackpoint/Trackpad) not working with new Thinkpad Yoga 14

Tags: 14.04, thinkpad, multi-touch, touchscreen, digitalpen

I just bought a new Thinkpad Yoga 14" Notebook/Convertible without any OS preinstalled (so no windows config magic was possible to i.e. pair the active pen). I installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 on it. I read that most things would work out of the box, like touch, the "active digitizer" (pen) and of course the trackpoint and touchpad. But I have several problems which may(?) be connected:

- Trackpoint middle key does not scroll. It's recognized as "middle mouse key" by the ubuntu mouse test (in system settings). Otherwise the point works fine.
- Touchpad does not have to finger scroll. I think it is not recognizes as a touchpad. I have no idea of how to configure hardware on linux.
- The touchscreen is not working. It just does nothing.
- The same goes for the pen. I read it's a wacom digitizer, but that wasn't official, so I have no idea.

**The most important for me is to be able to scroll, so the priority is to get the middle key of the trackpad or two finger scolling working correctly.** **Everything works fine on Ubuntu 15.04 btw**, but I really need Ubuntu 14.04. It's not that I love to be on the LTS, but I need to for a special project.

Here is some information about this computer:

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

If you need additional information please ask. Except to solutions to my problem, I'd also be interested why things do not work as well for me as for others. Thank you for your help.

Oh and there is indeed an eventually related question here on askubuntu. Although, the touchpad seems to be the only problem here, so I'm not sure. The rest seems to work for him. [Touchpad scroll not working in Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga 15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636540/touchpad-scroll-not-working-in-lenovo-thinkpad-yoga-15)

---

UPDATE

After installing the kernel using `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid`, everything works fine except the touchpad. The updated `xinput` output is:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID Finger touch                    id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID Pen stylus                      id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DualPoint Stick                           id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom HID Pen eraser                      id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated Camera                         id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

and `xinput list-props 14`

```
Device 'AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad':
    Device Enabled (139):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (263): 2
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (264):   4.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (265):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (266):    12.500000
    Synaptics Edges (294):  614, 3481, 307, 1740
    Synaptics Finger (295): 50, 55, 0
    Synaptics Tap Time (296):   180
    Synaptics Tap Move (297):   201
    Synaptics Tap Durations (298):  180, 180, 100
    Synaptics ClickPad (299):   1
    Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (300):  0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (301):    282
    Synaptics Two-Finger Width (302):   7
    Synaptics Scrolling Distance (303): -90, -90
    Synaptics Edge Scrolling (304): 0, 0, 0
    Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (305):   1, 1
    Synaptics Move Speed (306): 1.000000, 1.000000, 0.043687, 0.000000
    Synaptics Off (307):    2
    Synaptics Locked Drags (308):   1
    Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (309):   5000
    Synaptics Tap Action (310): 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Click Action (311):   1, 3, 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling (312): 0
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (313):    0.100000
    Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (314): 0
    Synaptics Circular Pad (315):   0
    Synaptics Palm Detection (316): 1
    Synaptics Palm Dimensions (317):    5, 40
    Synaptics Coasting Speed (318): 20.000000, 50.000000
    Synaptics Pressure Motion (319):    30, 160
    Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (320): 1.000000, 1.000000
    Synaptics Resolution Detect (321):  1
    Synaptics Grab Event Device (322):  0
    Synaptics Gestures (323):   1
    Synaptics Capabilities (324):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0
    Synaptics Pad Resolution (325): 38, 42
    Synaptics Area (326):   0, 0, 2400, 0
    Synaptics Soft Button Areas (327):  2457, 0, 0, 2400, 1638, 2457, 0, 2400
    Synaptics Noise Cancellation (328): 50, 50
    Device Product ID (259):    2, 8
    Device Node (260):  "/dev/input/event6"
```

Comment: Check Fn+Fx button that toggles the touchpad.

Comment: If that does not help give output of `xinput list-props 14`.

Comment: Uhm... I'm new with Thinkpads. I can't find a Fx button, and in case you mean a function key, I tried them all with Fn. None of them seems to lock it. I'll post the output in a second.

Comment: And it does not work at all or just scrolling?

Comment: The buttons under the touchpad work. If I switch the touchpad off in system settings, even the buttons won't work. So the touchpad is kind of enabled, but I can't move the cursor or scroll or anything. It's just the buttons.

Comment: Do this `sudo modprobe -r psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps`

Comment: Now the Touchpad works like before, without scrolling. Also, it's no longer recognized as a touchpad in system settings, it's just a mouse. The Trackpoint also lost it's scrolling functionality.

Comment: You will probably need to install a newer kernel that supports this revision from mainline ppa.

Comment: It strange, in 15.04 (live session) even the touchpad worked fine.

Comment: Hm. In this case it seems that you spoiled something. It is the same kernel and same driver.

Comment: I updated my answer. It is HWE stack from 15.04. It will get user space drivers updated. New synaptics will be there.

Comment: Still does not work, sorry. I'll look in the user manual, maybe I overlooked something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything works well in Ubuntu 15.04, then the solution is to upgrade kernel in Ubuntu 14.04.

You can do it by running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

and reboot.

You can also update xorg by

```
xserver-xorg-lts-vivid libqt5gui5 libgles1-mesa-lts-vivid libgles2-mesa-lts-vivid libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-vivid:i386 libglapi-mesa-lts-vivid:i386
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't think it would be that easy. My trackpoint works correctly, also does the touchscreen and the pen. Unfortunately, the touchpad does not. I can't move the cursor. The buttons work, though (probably part of the trackpoint). I tried to enable the touchpad using xinput, but it didn't work. I'll document it into my question. Would be awesome if we could solve even this last bit.

Comment: Please remove unrelated `lspci` and update `xinput`. And please do not do anything with `synaptics`.

Comment: I don't know why, but it works now. I just completely reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04.2 and installed linux-generic-lts-vivid, as you said. I don't know why it did not work before. I did not update xorg. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Probably you changed something in settings that is hard to guess. So you can accept the answer as it fixes the issue.